# Function from another js file don't do anything

Tags: node.js, api

I have this code on a file called `images.js` to search for specific images and download it. The same is a function exported for the main code:

```
function danbooru(){
    const Danbooru = require('danbooru')
    const booru = new Danbooru()
    booru.posts({tags: 'rating:safe rem_(re:zero) '}).then(posts =>{
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * posts.length)
        const post = posts[index]
        const url = booru.url(post.file_url)
        const name = `${post.md5}.${post.file_ext}`
        require('https').get(url, response=>{
            response.pipe(require('fs').createWriteStream('./images/' + name))
        })
    }) 
}

module.exports = danbooru
```

Then the function goes to to the main file `gacharoll.js` for execution on Twitter API:

```
const Twit = require ('twit');
const fs = require ('fs');
const path = require ('path');
const config = require (path.join(__dirname, 'config.js'));
const images = require('./images.js')
const T = new Twit (config);

images.danbooru

function upload_images(images){
    const image_path = path.join(__dirname, '/images/' + images.name);
    b64content = fs.readFileSync(image_path, {encoding: 'base64'});
    console.log (random_images);
    T.post('media/upload', {media_data: b64content}, function (err, data, response){
        if (err){
            console.log ('A ERROR HAS OCCURRED WHILE LOADING IMAGE');
            console.log (err);
        }
        else{
            console.log ('IMAGE LOADED');
            console.log ('TWEETING');
            const tweet_text = 'TESTE'
            T.post ('statuses/update', {status: tweet_text,media_ids: new Array(data.media_id_string)}),
            function (err,data,response){
                if (err){
                    console.log ('A ERROR HAS OCCURRED WHILE SENDING IMAGE');
                }
                else{
                    console.log (data);
                }
            }
        }
    })
}

setInterval (function(){
    upload_images(images);
}, 2000);
```

The thing is: The function from the ìmages.js is not executed on the main file gacharoll.js or not work properly since it won't download the image. When I execute the function on the images.js file it works normally. What is wrong with the main code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nothing wrong with the main code you just need to init the function

```
images.danbooru()
```

Comment: I get a ``images.danbooru is not a function`` when I do that.

Comment: inside of `module.exports = danbooru` in images.js use `exports.danbooru=danbooru`